# How to include a postscript image and change the fonts inside it?

Tags: fonts, include, postscript

I need to include a postscript file in a XeLaTeX document. The text in the PS file has western digits, but I need Persian digits. How should I do this?

Comment: You should take a look at the psfrag and psfragx packages (the latter loads the former and cooperates with babel).